# Start/stop internet sharing from a script?

Tags: terminal, network, wifi, internet-sharing, automation

Is there a way to start/stop internet sharing from the command line or maybe an apple script?

The thing is that I move around my laptop between home and work. At one place I get wireless internet (and thus I have to disable internet sharing), and at the other I get internet from an ethernet cable and set up the computer to share the internet to other devices by creating a small wireless network.

But it's getting a bit tedious having to go into System Preferences and start/stop the internet sharing every time I switch locations, so I would like to have a quick command or script to launch and do the switch on demand.

Any hints or ideas?

Comment: Mankoff,

when I run your suggestion:

    sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.InternetSharing.plist

it seems to run fine and even the sharing preferences gui is updated correctly when refreshed, however the connection is actually not working.  If I run the command again it even fails because it thinks its already loaded.

Also, if I run the "top" command to see the process running i do not see "InternetSharing" but if I start it in the preferences gui I will see the "InternetSharing" process actually running and the connection works.

Any ideas why I am h

Comment: Not sure why you get that behavior. I see "InternetSharing" in top (or easier, **ps aux | grep -i internet**).

Comment: I'm running OS X 10.6. If you have a different version maybe that is why...

Comment: Also, this should probably be a comment to my answer, not an answer in itself. Might want to delete the answer...

Comment: Yea, certainly this should be a comment to your answer, but for some reason I am not able to comment on there answers unless someone has already made a comment.  Maybe because I am a new user.    I am running OS X 10.6.4.  Another thing I noticed is that when I launch internet sharing in the preferences gui is that the process natd (network address translation daemon) also gets started.  I'm wondering if I also need to launch this process, currently investigating how to do this, there seem to be complex arguments needed to start this process.

Comment: mankoff,  when you run the command do you also get the other processes started, like bootpd and natd?  These process are started when I start internet sharing from the GUI, but no processes start when I execute the command.  I'm starting to think the process is crashing because the other process are not present.  That would also explain why Internet Sharing is gets checked in the gui put the process is actually not running.

Comment: @MikeZ: I converted these to comments for you.  Since you don't yet have enough reputation to comment in all places on the site, what you can do is create a new question and hopefully others can help you as well as mankoff.  This will help you gain enough reputation to post comments everywhere.  Check out http://apple.stackexchange.com/privileges for more info about reputation and privileges.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To start Internet Sharing from the CLI:

```
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.InternetSharing.plist
```

To stop, change the **load** to **unload**.

Note that if you have the pref pane open when you run this you will not see the change take effect immediately (the UI won't update), but it does work.

Comment: Strange, after a while, it stopped working. If I run the command and then open the pref pane I see that sharing is enabled, however the connection isn't actually being shared. If I manually stop and start sharing on the pref pane, then it works again without problems. Any clues about what could be wrong?

Comment: No idea why, but you can try other answers, they might work...

Comment: The receipe of Ken works! But... there is a bug (I'm hunting). You have to leave a 30 second delay after the `unload` to be able to do a `load` again. One good check command is `ps ax | egrep '[ /](PID|boo|nat)'`.

Comment: Doesn't work on 10.11.2 El Capitan: `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.InternetSharing.plist: No such file or directory`

Comment: try: /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.NetworkSharing.plist instead ;)

Comment: Since the System Preferences app doesn't require authentication how can we do it without using sudo/root?

Comment: Seems like `unload` doesn't work unless [SIP](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899) is removed (nothing I'd like to do)…

Answer (score 5):

One way of doing this is by GUI scripting—System Preferences doesn't have any Applescript support by default.

```
tell application "System Preferences" to set current pane to pane "com.apple.preferences.sharing"
delay 1
tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences"
    click checkbox 1 of row 8 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of window "Sharing" -- change to row 10 if you are using anything before Snow Leopard
    delay 1
    if (exists sheet 1 of window "Sharing") then
        click button "Start" of sheet 1 of window "Sharing"
    end if
end tell
ignoring application responses
    tell application "System Preferences" to quit
end ignoring
```

Comment: Perhaps, but it works and the answer is within the constraints of the OP's question: "Is there a way to start/stop internet sharing from the command line or maybe an *apple script*?" Downvoting really ought to be saved for the really egregious answers. Thanks

Comment: Hence no "official" downvote. :).

Comment: "works and is within constraints" makes me think we should have a new site: http://rubegoldberg.stackexchange.com

Comment: Isn't that what http://thedailywtf.com/ is for? ;-)

Comment: I've changed my accepted answer to this because the original answer from mankoff stopped working.

Comment: @Juan: In what way? Did you upgrade your OS?

Comment: @Philip: I don't have a clear idea, but it does seem to coincide with some upgrades to the OS. I had added some comments on [mankoff](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2488/start-stop-internet-sharing-from-a-script/2501#2501)'s answer since January, but only now I had a chance to investigate a bit more the issue and modify my scripts to use your solution instead.

Comment: @Juan: Just be forewarned that if Apple changes the layout of Systems Preferences and the Sharing pane with an upgrade, then my script has the real potential break as well because GUI scripting relies on very strict parameters.

Comment: This works fine on macOS Sierra, but with one problem: when I try to enable it when System Preferences is closed, I get this error: `System Events got an error: Can’t get button "Start" of sheet 1 of window "Sharing" of process "System Preferences".` It works fine when I try to disable it, though. The funny thing is, if System Preferences is *open* and I try to enable it, it works. Do you have any ideas as to why that would happen?

Answer (score 4):

I had far better results (for an already configured sharing setup) on 10.11.6 with the simple variations...

`sudo launchctl` **`start`** `com.apple.NetworkSharing`

and

`sudo launchctl` **`stop`** `com.apple.NetworkSharing`

*respectively.*

Answer (score 2):

## Definitive workaround to wifi-sharing constant breaking down in MacosX

I have found a system that finally **works** and when, less frequently wifi sharing breaks, it manages to recover it automatically in a minute.

The solution is a `~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.me.wifisharingup.plist` daemon with the next contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>com.juanfal.wifisharingup</string>

  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/Users/mi/bin/wifisharingup.sh</string>
  </array>
  <key>Nice</key>
  <integer>1</integer>

  <key>StartInterval</key>
  <integer>60</integer>

  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>

  <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
  <string>/Users/me/Library/Logs/wifisharingup.err</string>

  <key>StandardOutPath</key>
  <string>/Users/me/Library/Logs/wifisharingup.out</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

You can see, each minute it runs the simple script that follows.  Be careful making the previous plist be owned by the root and launch it with:

```
sudo chown root com.me.wifisharingup.plist
sudo launchctl load /Users/me/Library/LaunchAgents/com.me.wifisharingup.plist
```

The script it launches each minute (don't forget to make it executable) is:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [[ ! `ipconfig getifaddr en1` ]]; then
    /usr/sbin/networksetup -setairportpower en1 off
    /usr/sbin/networksetup -setairportpower en1 on
    echo `date` >> "/Users/me/Library/Logs/wifisharingup.err"
else
    touch "/Users/me/Library/Logs/wifisharingup.out"
fi
```

I think the simple periodically (each minute) call to `ipconfig getifaddr en1` refreshes something in what is the wifi sharing daemon.  Whatever it is, any moment the wifi sharing fails, it looses the self assigned IP address, and then, `ipconfig getifaddr en1` fails, so my script totally resets wifi, making it rebuild its previous status and recovering the wifi-sharing.

It has been working for days so far inside a MacMini without keyboard, mouse or monitor, but only plugged into the Ethernet and giving my wifi gadgets access to the world.

Answer (score 1):

I took a cue from mankoff's answer and wrapped it up in an AppleScript. I'm using this script from Automator so that I can easily use it as a service and give it a keyboard shortcut.

**Toggle Internet Sharing:**

```
register_growl()

try
    if isRunning("InternetSharing") then
        do shell script "launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.InternetSharing.plist" with administrator privileges

        if isRunning("InternetSharing") then
            error "Internet Connection Sharing was Not Disabled"
        else
            my growlnote("Success", "Internet Connection Sharing Disabled")
        end if

    else
        do shell script "launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.InternetSharing.plist" with administrator privileges

        if isRunning("InternetSharing") then
            my growlnote("Success", "Internet Connection Sharing Enabled")
        else
            error "Internet Connection Sharing was Not Enabled"
        end if

    end if

on error errMsg
    my growlnote("Error", errMsg)

end try

on isRunning(processName)
    try
        return 0 < length of (do shell script "ps ax | grep -v grep | grep " & processName)
    on error
        return false
    end try
end isRunning

on register_growl()
    try
        tell application "GrowlHelperApp"
            set the notificationsList to {"Success", "Warning", "Error"}
            register as application "Toggle Internet Connection Sharing" all notifications notificationsList default notifications notificationsList icon of application "Sharing"
        end tell
    end try
end register_growl

on growlnote(growltype, str)
    try
        tell application "GrowlHelperApp"
            notify with name growltype title growltype description str application name "Toggle Internet Connection Sharing"
        end tell
    end try
end growlnote
```

Comment: Does not really work on Lion for me. It displays the growl success message and toggles the option in the system preferences but the WiFi-symbol doesn't change to the sharing (and other devices can't see that the wifi is shared, so I think it isn't on :(

Answer (score 1):

I use the following script to toggle internet sharing on an early 2011 MacBook Pro / 10.11.3 El Capitan, so with newer hardware you might get away with shorter delays. It adopts ideas from several scripts posted for this purpose (localisation, turning wifi on/off using `networksetup`, close `System Preferences` when done).

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    reveal (pane id "com.apple.preferences.sharing")
    set localized_window to the localized name of the current pane
end tell

tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences"
    delay 1
    repeat with r in rows of table 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of window localized_window
        if (value of static text of r as text) starts with "Internet" then
            set sharingBool to value of checkbox of r as boolean
            select r
            if sharingBool is true
              do shell script "/usr/sbin/networksetup -setairportpower en1 off"
            else
              do shell script "/usr/sbin/networksetup -setairportpower en1 on"
            end if
            click checkbox of r
        end if
    end repeat
    delay 1

    if (exists sheet 1 of window localized_window) then
      click button "Start" of sheet 1 of window localized_window
    end if

end tell

ignoring application responses
  tell application "System Preferences" to quit
end ignoring
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Here’s a version (in AppleScript) that works for me in macOS 13.0 Ventura:

```
do shell script "open -b com.apple.systempreferences /System/Library/PreferencePanes/SharingPref.prefPane"

tell application "System Events"
    tell its application process "System Settings"
        repeat until window "Sharing" exists
        end repeat
        tell window "Sharing"
            set checkboxControl to checkbox "Internet Sharing" of group 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of group 1 of group 2 of splitter group 1 of group 1
            tell checkboxControl
                click
                its value as boolean -- wait untill the appearance of checkbox in the UI actually changes (for visual feedback)
                delay 0.3 -- wait a bit more
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell

tell application "System Settings" to quit
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at this (possibly off topic for Stack Overflow) question and its answer: [How to start/stop Internet Sharing using AppleScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2704889/2684).

> ```
> do shell script "/bin/launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.InternetSharing.plist" with administrator privileges
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The really easy way to do it is to combine @Philip's [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2488/start-stop-internet-sharing-from-a-script/2497#2497) with the [NetworkLocation](http://centrix.ca/NetworkLocation/) application. NL can tell where you are, and automatically run an AppleScript when it senses you've changed locations.

I think it's required software if you have a laptop—otherwise, it's a PITA to always have to manually reset several settings whenever I change locations.

Comment: Sounds like Marco Polo (http://www.symonds.id.au/marcopolo/) but without the Marco Polo steroids. :)

Comment: @Ian - That page says MP has known issues with Snow Leopard. The [Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/marcopolo-discuss) says "the MarcoPolo project isn't dead, per se, but it's being developed very slowly. Don't expect a new version soon." The [git repository](http://git.symonds.id.au/gitweb.cgi?p=marcopolo3.git) shows no update since September 2009. Sounds to me like the steroids might be catching up with someone… ;-)

Comment: Can't say I've had any issues with it on SL *save* for BlueTooth. I just don't use the BT enable/disable/detect feature and it works rather brilliantly. (But point taken)

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different than the other applescript posted (I think in a better way but…). Having options sometimes can help.

```
 tell application "System Preferences"
   activate
   reveal (pane id "com.apple.preferences.sharing")
 end tell

 tell application "System Events"
   tell process "System Preferences"
     try
       click checkbox of row 11 of table 1 of scroll area of group 1 of window "Sharing"

       if checkbox of row 11 of table 1 of scroll area of group 1 of window "Sharing" is equal to 1 then
         repeat until sheet of window 1 exists
           delay 0.5
         end repeat
       end if

       if (sheet of window 1 exists) then
         click button "Start" of sheet of window 1
       end if

       tell application "System Preferences" to quit
       activate (display dialog "Internet Sharing preferences sucessfully flipped")

     on error     
       activate
       display dialog "something went wrong in automation but you are probably in the right menu…"
       return false
     end try
   end tell
 end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

Before/after any configuration the interface or interfaces involved in sharing need to be turned off/on with:

```
networksetup -setairportpower en1 off
```

then on. (`networksetup -setairportpower en1 on`)

My wifi was listed as `en1`, to lookup yours use `networksetup -listnetworkserviceorder`. More to the point, when starting internet sharing you will need to add more detailed NAT functionality then just setting the enabled bit.

NAT is turned on/off with bit:  `-int 0` = off 
 `-int 1` = on

The only thing that is written in `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.nat.plist` with

```
defaults write /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.nat\
    NAT -dict Enabled -int 0
```

is

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>NAT</key>
        <dict>
                </dict>
                <key>Enabled</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

You will need to change your plist file to look like the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>NAT</key>
        <dict>
                <key>AirPort</key>
                <dict>
                        <key>40BitEncrypt</key>
                        <integer>1</integer>
                        <key>Channel</key>
                        <integer>0</integer>
                        <key>Enabled</key>
                        <integer>0</integer>
                        <key>NetworkName</key>
                        <string>FancyHostNome</string>
                        <key>NetworkPassword</key>
                        <data>
                        </data>
                </dict>
                <key>Enabled</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
                <key>NatPortMapDisabled</key>
                <false/>
                <key>PrimaryInterface</key>
                <dict>
                        <key>Device</key>
                        <string>en4</string>
                        <key>Enabled</key>
                        <integer>0</integer>
                        <key>HardwareKey</key>
                        <string></string>
                        <key>PrimaryUserReadable</key>
                        <string>InfiniBand</string>
                </dict>
                <key>PrimaryService</key>
                <string>XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX</string>
                <key>SharingDevices</key>
                <array>
                        <string>en1</string>
                </array>
        </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

As you can see my plist NAT file may need a little customization to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Since the GUI scripting solution posted previously requires international users to adjust the window and button names, I came up with a version that works with any system language. It also works for the other sharing option, and gives localized feedback about the sharing state. I use two different Automator services based on this, one to toggle file sharing and one to toggle internet sharing.

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    set current pane to pane "com.apple.preferences.sharing"
    set localized_window to the localized name of the current pane
    set localized_app to (localized string "System Preferences")
    set localized_ok to {localized string "OK"} -- File sharing
    set localized_start to {localized string "START"} -- Internet sharing
end tell
delay 0.3
tell application "System Events"
tell process "System Preferences"
    click checkbox 1 of row 8 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of window localized_window
    delay 0.2
    select row 8 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of window localized_window
    -- change row numbers to the service you want toggled
    if (exists sheet 1 of window localized_window) then
        try
            click button (localized_ok as string) of sheet 1 of window localized_window
        on error
            click button (localized_start as string) of sheet 1 of window localized_window
        end try
    end if
    set sharing_state to the value of item 1 of static text of group 1 of window localized_window
end tell

tell application "System Preferences" to quit
display notification sharing_state with title localized_app
--  display notification exists since OS 10.9, for older systems use: 
--  display dialog sharing_state buttons {localized_ok} default button 1 with title localized_app giving up after 1.5
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified one of the scripts above to toggle Internet Sharing on OSX MOJAVE (10.14), it works:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    reveal (pane id "com.apple.preferences.sharing")
    delay 0.3
    set current pane to pane "com.apple.preferences.sharing"
    delay 0.3
    set localized_window to the localized name of the current pane
    set localized_app to (localized string "System Preferences")
    set localized_ok to {localized string "OK"} -- File sharing
    set localized_start to {localized string "START"} -- Internet sharing
end tell
delay 0.3
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Preferences"
        click checkbox 1 of row 7 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of window localized_window
        delay 0.2
        select row 8 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of window localized_window
        -- change row numbers to the service you want toggled
        if (exists sheet 1 of window localized_window) then
            try
                click button (localized_ok as string) of sheet 1 of window localized_window
            on error
                click button (localized_start as string) of sheet 1 of window localized_window
            end try
        end if
        set sharing_state to the value of item 1 of static text of group 1 of window localized_window
    end tell
    
    tell application "System Preferences" to quit
    display notification sharing_state with title localized_app
    --  display notification exists since OS 10.9, for older systems use: 
    --  display dialog sharing_state buttons {localized_ok} default button 1 with title localized_app giving up after 1.5
end tell
```

Answer (score -2):

```
/usr/bin/defaults write /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.nat NAT -dict Enabled -int 0
```

Comment: Does this toggle the sharing?