# What are the differences between the AT&T and Verizon versions of iPhone 4?

Tags: iphone, cellular-carriers

Besides working on their respective carriers, what are the similarities and differences between the AT&T iPhone 4 and Verizon iPhone 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the differences between CDMA and GSM, the antenna notches have been moved around. There are also 4 now instead of 3, and as a result of adding a notch on the left side of the phone, the mute switch is slightly lower on the Verizon iPhone 4 than the AT&T iPhone 4, which could cause cases made for the AT&T iPhone 4 to not fit the Verizon iPhone 4 properly:

[image]

Though this may change in a future version of iOS, right now the Verizon iPhone 4 has a "Personal Hotspot" feature to share the data connection with up to 5 devices. In contrast, the AT&T iPhone 4 supports tethering through USB or Bluetooth only, and only to 1 device:

[image]

Finally, because the Verizon iPhone 4 runs on Verizon's CDMA, it does not support simultaneous data and voice, unlike the AT&T iPhone 4 which does over 3G.

Answer (score -2):

Engadget summarized the differences...

http://www.engadget.com/2011/01/11/atandt-iphone-4-vs-verizon-iphone-4-whats-changed/

Comment: Please do not simply link to another article.

Comment: @Philip Would it be good to copy & paste it here ? No offense to @Kyle's answer.... and I don't think so it deserves to be down voted ..

Comment: @Philip - this is lame, you shouldn't minus an answer for being a link. Are you THAT new to Stack Overflow???

Comment: @garikapati - I plus'd your answer to offset the unfair minus

Comment: @Andrey: I am far from new to the site.

Comment: @garikapati: Actually answer the question and provide links to support it. If you don't have an answer that directly answers the question, then don't answer it. [...]

Comment: [...] "Linking is not a bad thing as long as you actually provide some context to your answer. If all you are going to do is post a link in your answer, you aren't really answering, you are just providing a detour for the user. At the very least you could explain where the link goes and what it is going to show the user (maybe even quote some of important stuff in the answer so that the OP doesn't have to click the link to possibly answer their question)." From meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7515/why-is-linking-bad [...]

Comment: [...] I'm not saying that linking is bad, but just that simply posting a link isn't what is considered a sufficient answer in SE. From the same thread: "One problem with links is that they can die/expire, the pages on the target site get reorganised or deleted, and the link is no longer valid." and "posting only a link as an answer requires the person reading the answer to perform an additional action (click on the link) in order to see your answer" [...]

Comment: [...] All of those comments were voted up three times each at the time of this writing at this thread: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2488/start-stop-internet-sharing-from-a-script/, @Martín's answer where he did the exact same thing. The -1 stays.