# Turn Wifi Off via command line

Tags: network, security, internet-sharing

I'm sharing my internet in work and forgot to turn it off! Does anyone know how I can do it via the command line? I have SSH access but thats it. D'oh.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Start/stop internet sharing from a script?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2488/start-stop-internet-sharing-from-a-script)

Answer (score 16):

You could use this to turn it off:

```
sudo ifconfig en1 down
```

And if you want to get it back up, just type **up**, instead of **down**

Just make sure that en1 is the right interface or you can easily kill off your ssh access :)

P.S. As **Lri** noted in the comments below, you can quickly disable the correct network interface with just 1 line:

```
sudo ifconfig `networksetup -listallhardwareports | grep -E '(Wi-Fi|AirPort)' -A 1 | grep -o "en."` down
```

This will detect the correct Airport/wireless device and will turn it off

Comment: Or `en0` on MacBook Airs. You can find out the device name with `networksetup -listallhardwareports | grep -E '(Wi-Fi|AirPort)' -A 1 | grep -o "en."`.

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
networksetup -setairportpower en0 off
```