# How can I enable Internet sharing without using the GUI or AppleScript?

Tags: snow-leopard, preferences, internet-sharing

for some rather strange reason my sharing preferences tab crashes (it's a long story and there seems to be no good solution for it, it's looking for a ui object that no longer exists).

Anyway, I want to enable internet sharing to share my macbook's internet connection with my iPad but I can't find a way to do it without the gui or apple script (which basically calls the gui).

The problem is I need to both (1) set up and (2) run the internet sharing daemon. Running the daemon is easy but I can't configure it.

So far I am thinking I need to 1- enable routing 2- run natd 3- make sure firewall is properly configured 4- make a peer to peer wireless network on wifi.
Another option is to use `sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.InternetSharing.plist` the problem is I need at least a valid Snow Leopard .plist file for this to work.

Another solution I tried is to use a virtual machine (I use an Ubuntu VM in Parallels) to do the connection sharing. It works but it's too much work.

(In case you are wondering, when I click on shring in the preferences tab it crashes and in console I get an error like "unknown Class 'AppleSharing_NatManager' using 'NSObject' instead")

Any comments?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Start/stop internet sharing from a script?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2488/start-stop-internet-sharing-from-a-script)

Comment: No, I read that before posting. Usually what people need to do when they want to automate Internet sharing using a script is to use Apple scripts (which basically "clicks" the correct buttons and check boxes to do the job. As I explained I cannot use that because my preferences UI is broken. I need a more "unixy" way of doing this.

Comment: Don't read the selected answer, read the link one, which has the most votes, and does not use GUI scripting.

Comment: @Ali: I guess it might be easier to fix your preference pane ;-) Have you tried whether it opens successfully when launched from a different user account? And have you tried moving the different .plist file out of the way to see if the problem persists?

Comment: @mankoff you're so humble, not even mentioning that it was your answer not selected but with the most votes. :) +1!

Comment: @ghoppe aw shucks :). Anyway, I tried to link to my answer but the software stripped it to the question only, making it hard to find...

Comment: @Ali I realize my linked solution doesn't work for you. My suggestion: Fix the problem, not the symptom. Find out why your pref pane/plist is crashing, be it an odd UI object or an invalid plist, and fix that.

Comment: @Ali is your UI language english? I think there are sometimes problems with other languages.

Comment: @mankoff My UI is English. I have other keyboards (Dvorak and Persian) installed but the UI is standard US English.

Comment: @Asmus @mankoff , I have tried to solve the "problem" but it won't budge! I don't want to reinstall my OS.

Comment: @makoff , thanks. Your solution for starting the daemon works fine. but my problem is I need a proper plist or other means to configure my internet sharing. Without the proper configuration running the daemon wont help much.

Comment: can anyone who share their plist with me? I need to share my lan Internet to my Wifi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Austin and others, I finally solved the problem! I thought damn it, this is a Unix box, i should be able to find out what's going on! I found another Snow Leopard machine at work which never had Internet Sharing turned on and in a terminal I ran:
    `touch now && sudo find -x / -newer now`

and I got a short list of files that always show up (spotlight indexes, log files in /private/log and if you are using FileVault a bunch of encrypted sparse bundles)

then I enabled Internet sharing and this time I ran:
    `sudo find -x / -newer now` 
obviously without the "touch now". 
It turns out that other than a bunch of log files and other junk there are a hand full of files that are modified. 
I copied them all over to my machine and modified the interface names and few other hostname and ip addresses and stuff like that. 
The problem happend with    `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.nat.plist`    there is a primary service key there which is set to a UUID and it is different on every machine that I tested (2 machines actually) and it does not work from if you just copy it from one machin to next.

*** IF YOU ARE IN A HURRY JUST READ THIS PART ***

From the start I avoided reinstalling my OS because I had so many Installations and configurations that I didn't want to loose. It turned out that if you use the original DVD that comes with your machine and reinstall your OS ALL YOUR APPLICATIONS, HOME DIRECTORY, custom modifications, mac ports and fink installations, preferences, network mounts, network locations, developer tools, ALL ARE PRESERVED. BUT IT REINSTALLS THE CORE SYSTEM COMPONENTS that fixes my preferences sharing pane!

Answer (score 2):

The plist that others have mentioned (`/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.InternetSharing.plist`) never seems to change regardless of the state of Internet Sharing -- at least under Snow Leopard.

I think the answer lies somewhere in `/usr/libexec/InternetSharing` and `/etc/boopd.plist`.

First, try running:

`sudo /usr/libexec/InternetSharing -d`

You will probably see messages like the following:

`InternetSharing[40307]: InternetSharing starting`

`/etc/bootpd.plist is empty/missing`

`InternetSharing[40307]: no primary service specified, exiting`

It turns out that `/etc/bootpd.plist` is created when Internet Sharing is started from the Sharing pref pane, and it is deleted when Internet Sharing is turned off.

If you are feeling adventurous, you could try manually creating the plist file.  I enabled Internet Sharing with Ethernet shared to AirPort and copied the text of the resulting `/etc/bootpd.plist` file to a pastebin here: http://pastebin.com/gQVzARfa

This plist doesn't contain all the necessary settings (e.g. SSID for the wireless shared connection), so I'm guessing it won't work on its own.  I'm still looking for the other settings and will update this answer if I find them.  (It's possible some are passed in as parameters to `/usr/libexec/InternetSharing`, but I can't find any documentation on that.)

Once you have created the plist file, try running `sudo /usr/libexec/InternetSharing -d` again.  We may be able to work through this one error at a time.  At this point it's really an academic exercise, as it would be far easier to reinstall your OS to fix your pref pane issue.  ;]

If by some miracle it does start, I believe `/usr/libexec/InternetSharing -q` will stop sharing.

Messing with your system files is always somewhat risky, so make sure you have a recent backup of your important files (I recommend [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/)).

Comment: @Austin man that's cool, it turns out that even if I make the /etc/bootpd.plist if just touch it or copy the content you providid into it (even if I set its permission to 444) it would be removed when I run `/usr/libexec/InternetSharing` but the cool thing is that I can connect to my mac from my iPad now! and SSH into it. It still does not route the packets out so I don't have Internet on my iPad but that is progress. By the way the AirPort icon changes to an upward arrow which I think is the Interent sharing sign. I am also a Dropbox fan!

Comment: @Austin by the way '/usr/libexec/InternetSharing' does not return for me (I joust get stuck until I hit ctrl-c) and I don't see the third line of what you mentioned above (the 'InternetSharing[40307]: no primary service specified, exiting').

Comment: @Ali Interesting that it hangs before exiting...  Could be a symptom of the same problem that is plaguing your pref panes.  Perhaps try taking a look at the Console (`/Applications/Utilities/Console.app`) and see if there are any useful messages there.  The "up arrow" is an indication of AirPort Internet Sharing, so that's a good sign, at least.

Comment: @Austin, It gets stuck, it does not crash, in the console I see "5/2/11 3:30:18 PM UserEventAgent[410] **** ERROR: SCNetworkSignatureCopyActiveIdentifiers returned nil" . Which according to this header file (http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/configd/configd-210/SystemConfiguration.fproj/SCNetworkSignature.h?txt) should return a list of available networks or something.

Comment: @Austin, Do you know if I can just enable routing (packet forwarding) between the two network interfaces? that is I believe the last piece of my puzzle.

Comment: @Ali You may be looking for the NAT daemon (`/usr/sbin/natd`)?  Docs here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/natd.8.html  Be sure to follow the steps at the bottom first.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the UUID issue you could look the machine’s UUID with `system_profiler | grep 'Hardware UUID'` and updated the file.

This is what I did when I had to grab a copy of `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.nat.plist` from another Mac when I notice my machine didn’t have it.

Despite all this I’m still stuck at trying to share my internet connection from ethernet to Airport.

Running `sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.InternetSharing.plist` turns the Internet Sharing preferences gui on but with incorrect settings (sharing from Aiport to ethernet - I need the reverse).

Despite the launchctl load request the error logs still show the same as the output for `sudo /usr/libexec/InternetSharing -d`

```
Oct 14 01:54:39 boatdelight-lm InternetSharing[52015]: InternetSharing starting
Oct 14 01:54:39 boatdelight-lm InternetSharing[52015]: no primary service specified, exiting
```

I’ve tried this with and without manually creating the `/etc/bootpd.plist` file.

Answer (score 0):

```
man networksetup
```

or

```
man systemsetup
```

might do it.

Comment: thanks I didn't know about these two commands. But there is nothing there about Internet sharing (or nat or routing for that matter).