# How can I enable SSH without using the gui or apple script on snow leopard?

Tags: script, ssh, crash, preferences

A while back here [How can I enable Internet sharing without using the GUI or AppleScript?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11855/how-can-i-enable-internet-sharing-without-using-the-gui-or-apple-script-on-snow-l) I asked if any one knows how to enable Internet sharing without using GUI or apple script, I still have that problem but I thought this one should be easier, I want to be able to SSH into my machine but sure enough I can't go to the "sharing" pane in the Preferences (It crashes). How can I start sshd?

Comment: I think that the issue to look into solving is why the Sharing preference pane is crashing. Does the system.log tell you anything useful?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can enable SSH from the Terminal with:

```
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
```

(note that you need to run this as an admin, and it'll ask for your admin password, which won't echo as you type.)

Answer (score 2):

Here's the command to start VNC sharing -- not SSH, but perhaps it will help you (be sure to replace the password with your own!):

```
sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart -activate -configure -access -on -clientopts -setvnclegacy -vnclegacy yes -clientopts -setvncpw -vncpw PutYourOwnPasswordHere -restart -agent -privs -all
```

Then you should be able to log in using a VNC client with the password you specified.

Here's the command to stop sharing:

```
sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart -deactivate -configure -access -off
```

Note that the Sharing pane will NOT show that sharing is active when you turn it on this way via the command line!

Source: http://technotes.twosmallcoins.com/?p=279

Comment: Wow! @Austin that works, thank you, do you happen to know tho answer to my original question too? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11855/how-can-i-enable-internet-sharing-without-using-the-gui-or-apple-script-on-snow-l

Comment: I took a crack at it.  Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo systemsetup -setremotelogin on
sudo systemsetup -setremotelogin off
```

Comment: Thanks. Also is there a way to add remove users who can ssh. You know in the UI you can choose who can use the "remote login".