# Enable SSH and Remote Management via Profile Manager

Tags: ssh, server.app, profile-manager, open-directory

I've been working on getting some iMacs enrolled on an Open Directory, and using Profile Manager to push some settings that are useful for our office (some essential Dock items, a few security policies, nothing fancy).

What I'd really like to do, though, is be able to enable (at least) SSH, and preferably Screen Sharing or Remote Management. I've looked at all the options in Profile Manager, and it looks like that isn't directly possible. So, I suspect I'll need to create a custom payload for something like the `com.apple.RemoteManagement` domain.  Only, i have no idea what to put in there, and my Google-fu fails me.

I've tried using XCode Instruments to watch for filesystem changes when enabling and disabling the Screen Sharing or Remote Management settings using the System Preferences app, but haven't turned up anything useful.

Comment: Here are the command line tools you could disassemble / trace: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/13102/how-can-i-enable-ssh-without-using-the-gui-or-apple-script-on-snow-leopard - I would be surprised there is a profile for this, but let's see what comes to light. ( `systemsetup` and `kickstart` )

Comment: Good idea @bmike!  Unfortunately, i'm being bitten by SIP, i cannot attach to processes using `dtruss` :(.  After spending about 30 minutes on that i am going to have to move on (i tried suggestions involving copying binaries to `/tmp`, then re-signing them, but for that i needed a code signing identity, and before i knew it i was shaving a yak in a field somewhere).  I'll get back to this some time later.  Thanks though!