# Mac refuses to sleep: Reset PreventSystemSleep?

Tags: macos, sleep-wake

For the last month, my Mac has refused to go to sleep – even when commanding it to do so. The screen goes black, but the computer is still on.

I have checked Apple's [support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204760) and made sure that the *Energy Saver* settings are correct. I've also checked under the *Energy* tab in *Activity Monitor* and can't find anything that is `Preventing Sleep`. I have followed the instructions to reset the  [SMC](https://support.apple.com/HT201295) and [NVRAM](https://support.apple.com/HT204063).

In Terminal, when I do `pmset -g assertions` I get these results:

```
Assertion status system-wide:
   BackgroundTask                 1
   ApplePushServiceTask           0
   UserIsActive                   1
   PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep    0
   PreventSystemSleep             1
   ExternalMedia                  0
   PreventUserIdleSystemSleep     0
   NetworkClientActive            0

Listed by owning process:
   pid 111(hidd): [0x0000014d00090344] 00:08:52 UserIsActive named: "com.apple.iohideventsystem.queue.tickle" 
    Timeout will fire in 367 secs Action=TimeoutActionRelease
   pid 55(configd): [0x0000005f0007016b] 00:12:50 DenySystemSleep named: "InternetSharingPreferencePlugin" 
   pid 42(UserEventAgent): [0x0000006d000b0170] 00:12:36 BackgroundTask named: "com.apple.metadata.mds_stores.power" 
    Created for PID: 232. 
Kernel Assertions: 0x10c=USB,BT-HID,MAGICWAKE
   id=501  level=255 0x4=USB mod=01/01/70 01:00 description=com.apple.usb.externaldevice.fd140000 owner=USB Receiver
   id=502  level=255 0x4=USB mod=01/01/70 01:00 description=com.apple.usb.externaldevice.fa120000 owner=IOUSBHostDevice
   id=503  level=255 0x4=USB mod=01/01/70 01:00 description=com.apple.usb.externaldevice.fa130000 
   id=505  level=255 0x100=MAGICWAKE mod=01/01/70 01:00 description=en0 owner=en0
   id=506  level=255 0x100=MAGICWAKE mod=01/01/70 01:00 description=en1 owner=en1
   id=507  level=255 0x8=BT-HID mod=01/01/70 01:00 description=com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver owner=BNBTrackpadDevice
   id=508  level=255 0x8=BT-HID mod=01/01/70 01:00 description=com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver owner=AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard
Idle sleep preventers: IODisplayWrangler
```

`PreventSystemSleep` is active `1` for some reason.

Misc. info:

- I had the old *Caffeine* app installed and made sure it wasn't active and then uninstalled the application. I'm not sure how to check if the system is "caffeinated", but I don't think `caffeinate` is stuck.
- I've tried shutting down my other network devices while troubleshooting and don't believe that there is some network service causing the problem.

Is there a way to check what's keeping `PreventSystemSleep` active? Is there a way to disable it?

Comment: Why not reset SMC and NVRAM? Simple but often effective procedure...

Comment: @n1000 I have now reset SMC and NVMRAM. Unfortunately, I still get the same results with `PreventSystemSleep 1`.

Comment: @Winterflags - I need more coffee....

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From your sleep assertions, it appears you have *Internet Sharing* enabled. Try disabling it via **** → **System Preferences** → **Sharing** → **Internet Sharing**.

Comment: Disabling Internet Sharing solved the issue. Which is silly because the only connection that was enabled is *Thunderbolt Bridge* and there's not even another computer attached to it...

Comment: FYI See this [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48163/is-it-possible-to-configure-internet-sharing-to-allow-the-computer-to-sleep) for ways to allow the Mac to sleep while Internet Sharing is enabled.

Answer (score 2):

In some cases, an unprinted document in offline printer could cause issues like this.

To try to solve this problem, go to System Preferences → Printers & Scanners and delete offline printers.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion – I removed offline printers but it didn't help with my particular issue (also after reboot).