# How can I toggle internet sharing from the command line?

Tags: command-line, internet-sharing, quicksilver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Start/stop internet sharing from a script?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2488/start-stop-internet-sharing-from-a-script)

There are applescripts / automator scripts that help to turn on / off internet sharing, but they do not work consistently (plus, using something that simulates clicking is sooooo 20th century).

Are there ways to activate or deactivate internet sharing from the command line? Ideally I'll be running the script in Terminal or via Quicksilver.

Comment: Yep, duplicate, which I'd missed. Interesting that the tags between this post and the other are totally different.

Comment: Having duplicate questions merged with differing tags and wording of the core question is actually a feature of how we handle closed questions. Your framing of the question will make the answers we already have more likely to be seen by others searching for exactly what you did. Ideally, we'd have several versions of every good question with all but the canonical version closed to avoid answers being duplicated / spread. A decent spread on questions is a good thing.

Comment: Also, if and when that question gets edited or yours changes to diverge from the duplicate, we can edit here and re-open if needed.