# Turn on Internet Sharing from Terminal (on Mojave)

Tags: macos, command-line, mojave

In System Preferences > Sharing, there is a way to turn on Internet Sharing so that devices connected to my laptop can use its Internet connection.

[Start/stop internet sharing from a script?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2488/start-stop-internet-sharing-from-a-script) recommends to manually load `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.InternetSharing.plist` but this file doesn't exist on Mojave.

So how do I turn Internet Sharing from Terminal on Mojave?

Comment: I’m going to tag this command line since that’s really the tool - shell / bash / whatever. Whether you use iterm / bash / scripting framework - this isn’t so much about terminal app as command-line control.

Comment: @bmike thanks, i don't even use Terminal.app. I didn't think to read the tag summary (i don't actually know how on mobile when adding it to the question), but you're absolutely right i was meaning to ask after a command-line solution.

Comment: Sorry to follow up so late, but is it possible that `com.apple.InternetSharing.plist` is the same as `com.apple.NetworkSharing.plist` (which is visible in my `/System/Library` folder in Mojave)?